# How do I set up a postgresql database in Windows Powershell?

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to follow a guide to setup a postgres database using a postgres sql file on my computer. The instructions I'm trying to work off of are below:

> 1. Create the database. This will create a database called `database1`.
>
> ```
> psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE database1;
> ```
>
> 2. Import the data into postgres
>
> ```
> psql -U postgres database1 < db1.sql
> ```
>
> 3. Done!

What I'm having problems with is step 1. I set up psql with the Windows environment path variable and have psql working in powershell as far as I can tell. However, the command from step 1 doesn't run properly. I believe this is because it's formatted incorrectly - probably, it's missing an apostrophe or something similar. Can anyone tell me how to get the first command to run correctly?

I tried adding an apostrophe around database1, i.e.
"psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE 'database1';"

but then I just get some messages saying
"psql: warning: extra command-line argument "DATABASE" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "database1" ignored"

Hope you guys don't mind me asking such a simple question. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Did you try `psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE database1;'`

Comment: I think you should try: `psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE database1;'`

Comment: I had not tried those, no. That worked perfectly, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE database1;"`

Alternatively, you can use the Postgres shell and enter user details based on the prompts given, and then create a database using `CREATE DATABASE database1;`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much!